# Plotly map projection types

Tags: plotly

Trying to find a list of the different types of projects available in plotly

*Projection types from different sample:*

```
projection = list(type = "equirectangular")
projection = list(type = 'azimuthal equal area'),
projection = dict(type = 'Mercator')
```

Any online documentation would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2021 answer:**

This code will show you every possible projection (with exception of `transverse mercator` which doesn't work with this example data, but when I tested with different data it worked).

Map charts will be saved to `./projections/` folder.

Source of list of projections: https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#map-projections

```py
import plotly.express as px
from pathlib import Path

df = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=geojson, color="Bergeron",
                    locations="district", featureidkey="properties.district")

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":10,"t":50,"l":10,"b":10})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', resolution=50,scope='north america')


projections = ['equirectangular', 'mercator', 'orthographic', 'natural earth',
 'kavrayskiy7', 'miller', 'robinson', 'eckert4', 'azimuthal equal area', 
 'azimuthal equidistant', 'conic equal area', 'conic conformal',
 'conic equidistant', 'gnomonic', 'stereographic', 'mollweide', 'hammer',
 'transverse mercator', 'albers usa', 'winkel tripel', 'aitoff', 'sinusoidal']


Path('./projections/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for p in projections:
    fig.update_geos(projection_type=p)
    fig.update_layout(title=p)
    path=f'./projections/{p}.png'
    fig.write_image(file=path,width=960,height=540,scale=2)
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more comprehensive listing of the world projections:

1. Equirectangular
2. Mercator
3. Orthographic
4. Natural earth
5. Kavrayskiy7
6. Miller
7. Robinson
8. Eckert4
9. Azimuthal equal area
10. Azimuthal equidistant
11. Conic equal area
12. Conic conformal
13. Conic equidistant
14. Gnomonic
15. Stereographic
16. Mollweide
17. Hammer
18. Transverse mercator

This github displays the different projections:
http://etpinard.github.io/plotly-dashboards/map-projections/

A [list of map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) (with images) is available on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dropdown with all of the supported projections:

https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not list the projections anymore. I could find the avaiable projections in [plotly.py source code](https://github.com/dustinstansbury/quick_plotly/blob/master/quick_plotly.py#L65). But I think that plotly.js really uses [D3.js projections](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/Geo-Projections/).

Here they are:

- equirectangular
- mercator
- orthographic
- natural earth
- kavrayskiy7
- miller'
- robinson'
- eckert4'
- azimuthal equal area
- azimuthal equidistant
- conic equal area
- conic conformal
- conic equidistant
- gnomonic
- stereographic
- mollweide
- hammer
- transverse mercator
- albers usa